# Basic (username/password) authentication with Auth0 .NetCore Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, swagger, auth0

I have an API which will be exposed to public which uses Auth0 for Authentication and has swagger enabled to view/document the endpoint.

I have 2 applications configured in Auth0

- Web (used to authenticate users who access my UI, this calls the API and works fine. )
- API (used to authenticate my API, swagger is currently using this to get a bearer token )

I understand that this is wrong as everyone who comes to Swagger will have access to everything.

So I need to create a controller endpoint `/Authentication?username=a&password=b` where I can take that username, hash the password and send it to Auth0, get a token and return this to user.
Now user can use this token and Authorise swagger.
I want to let know that this API will be accessed by other third party applications. So I need an endpoint where in they can hit and get a token and make other API calls.

A sample code that I have, which is obviously not working is given below.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> Login(string username, string password)
{
    var stringContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
      {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", this.Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"]),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("audience", this.Configuration["Auth0:Audience"]),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("connection", "Username-Password-Authentication"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid profile email"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response_type", "code"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:5000"),
      });
    this.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    dynamic response = await this.client.PostAsync($"{this.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/usernamepassword/login", stringContent).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic result = JObject.Parse(response);
    return result.access_token;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: _"create a controller endpoint /Authentication?username=a&password=b"_ - Please [don't send passwords in the query string](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29598). Either use the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) `Authorization: Basic ...` header or send the username/password in the request body.

Comment: Thanks and I really appreciate the concern and I totally understand that it has to go in a request body, password has to be hashed etc.. It has been given as a sample code to explain what I am trying to achieve in here. The question is how can this username and password be provided to Auth0? Appreciate your help.